# Issues hitting break points whilst debugging Scrapy in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: python, visual-studio, scrapy

I've inherited a load of completely undocumented Scrapy based web scrapers, some of which are not working and I'm trying to fix. I'm using Visual Studio 2019 for the job.

I'm new to Python and Scrapy, so I'm probably missing something,  but I cannot get VS to stop on breakpoints in the Python code within the individual functions of the spider classes.

Basically, I would like to break within the 'parse' functions of the spider so I can see what is going on as it picks through the data returned from the scraped site. At the moment it will not and break and any print statements I add do not print out either.

It looks like it's just not hitting that area of the code, but it must be as I can see the results of their work in the output file.

Sorry, I can't display code here due to policy.

Thanks
W

Answer (score 0):

As usual, found the answer almost as soon as I posted...

I'm using VS2019...This link gave me the answer:
https://newbedev.com/debugging-scrapy-project-in-visual-studio-code

In case it doesn't work...

Create a runnper.py script in the same directory as your scarpy.cfg file.
Put this in it:

```
import os
from scrapy.cmdline import execute
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
try:
    execute(
        [
            'scrapy',
            'crawl',
            'YOUR SPIDER NAME HERE',
            '-o',
            'out.json',
        ]
    )
except SystemExit:
    pass
```

Change 'YOUR SPIDER NAME HERE' to your spider name.
Set this runner file to be the start up file in VS.
Place your breakpoints in the spider you are you put in 'YOUR SPIDER NAME HERE'
Debug, and it should break.
Worked for me in Visual Studio 2019.